# remove transparency from bootstrap tooltip

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

The standard .tooltip from twitter bootstrap has a transparency that I would like to remove.

This my HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="btn
btn-info" 
style="margin:10px;" 
data-toggle="tooltip" 
data-placement="bottom" 
data-html="true"
title="MERKNAD 1 Denne klassifiseringen er i henhold til NS-EN 13501-2. <br /><br /> MERKNAD 2 Valgene 11-16 gjelder bærende konstruksjoner, valgene 21-24 gjelder kun integritet, valgene 31-37 gjelder både integritet og isolasjon, valgene 41-46 gjelder bærende skiller konstruksjoner med isolasjonskrav, og valgene 51-54 gjelder seksjoneringsvegger og dekker.">Hover</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
.tooltip > .tooltip-inner {
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 10px;
    max-width: 450px;
    color: black;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: white;
    background: white;
    opacity: 1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
.tooltip > .tooltip-arrow {
    border-bottom-color: black;
}
```

Also I made a JSFiddle to illustrate, here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/fiddlejan/xpwhknja/

If you hover over the button you can see how the transparent tooltip text is also showing the text underneath.

I tried:

```
opacity: 1.0;
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
```

But it does't seem to work...

Comment: @A.Wolff It is for me in Chrome

Comment: for me In firefox also.

Comment: @A.Wolff It's a very slight transparency. If you look close, you will see it

Comment: Oh guys you are correct. I'm curently testing it on laptop with some sun in eyes... My bad, sorry!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Add `.tooltip.in{opacity:1!important;}` in css..By default it is `0.9` that's why background is transparent
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BDhara/xpwhknja/10/)

Answer (score 30):

Bootstrap v4.0:

```
.tooltip.show {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Add to your `.tooltip` class also opacity 1, but with flag `important`.
See updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Narek_T/xpwhknja/9/)

And in your fiddle you connected `bootstrap.min.css` directly in html. So in your website you can write

```
.tooltip.in {
  opacity: 1;
  filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

without any `!important` and it will work. But in fiddle it doesn't work because you didn't use for that css `External Resources`

Its because in your bootstrap.css you have

```
.tooltip.in{filter:alpha(opacity=90);opacity:.9}
```

Comment: You should use any more specific rule instead of using `!important` statement

Comment: Surely you can override it with a parent element selector rather than !important

Comment: @A.Wolff, @ShaneQful, you're right. But note, topic starter placed links directly to `<html>` in JSFiddle. If connect that styles normally, with `external resources` so no need for '!important'.

Answer (score 3):

Please use !important on opacity like-

```
.tooltip > .tooltip-inner {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 450px;
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: white;
  background: white;

  opacity: 1.0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
} 

.tooltip > .tooltip-arrow { border-bottom-color:black; }

.tooltip.in {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When I needed to reduce the transparency of the tooltip provided by **`ngbTooltip`** this is what I added in my CSS file.

Note: I was using **Bootstrap v4**

```
::ng-deep .tooltip.show {
    opacity: 1!important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **SCSS and Bootstrap 4** you can simply override the `$tooltip-opacity` variable as follows:

```
$tooltip-opacity: 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this class :

```
.tooltip.in {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to be specific as the exact call is two classes in one element

```
    .tooltip.in{
opacity: 0.9;
}
```

in boostrap.min.css

So just override with opacity of 1;

Hope this helps, if not you will need !important or another parent element in front - but cant see your loading order on the page so not sure on precedence.

Comment: Ya, `body .tooltip.in{
  opacity: 1;
}` fixes it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.tooltip {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```